# mocked method is returning Null

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing, mockito

I'm attempting to mock a few method calls but unfortunately I keep getting null returned.  Can you help me point out where I may be going wrong?  I am using the when().thenReturn() and I feel like I mocked the return variable correctly.  Many thanks in advance.  I'm new to JUnit and Mockito so my apologies if I'm missing anything obvious.

ServiceTest.java

```
@IntegrationTest
public class ServiceTest extends TransactionalTest {
    private HistoryService orderHistoryService;
    private CMSSiteModel website;

@Mock
protected DefaultWebService orderDetailsServiceWrapper;
@Mock
protected WebsiteService websiteService;    

@Before
public void setUp()
{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    website = mock(CMSSiteModel.class);
}

@Test
public void testFindOrderDetailsByConfirmationNumber() {

    when(websiteService.getCurrentSite()).thenReturn(website);

    final ResponseType response = orderHistoryService.findOrderDetailsByConfirmationNumber(OrderTestUtils.CONFIRMATION_NUMBER, OrderTestUtils.LOCATION_NUMBER);

    Assert.assertEquals("Incorrect Approver Name", OrderTestUtils.APPROVER_NAME, response.getApprovedByName());
}
```

and Service.java

```
public class HistoryService implements OrderHistoryService {

    @Autowired
    private WebsiteService websiteService;

    @Override
    public OrderDetailsServiceResponseType findOrderDetailsByConfirmationNumber(String confirmationNumber, String locationNumber) {

        CMSSiteModel test = websiteService.getCurrentSite();  //returning null
        odsrHeader.setSource(test.getOrderSource());

    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you set `websiteService` in `Service`?

Comment: Basically, where is `orderHistoryService` constructed and how?

Comment: Most likely you forgot to inject the mocks in the class-under-test as @SotiriosDelimanolis said. Take a look at http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html for a quick and nice way of doing it

Comment: Is it returning `null` or are you getting a `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are assuming that Mockito will automatically inject the `WebsiteService` into the `OrderHistoryService`. You need to annotate the `OrderHistoryService` with `@InjectMocks` before Mockito will do this. `InjectMocks` will create a normal instance of the class and then attempt to fill its fields with any mocked or spy classes that have been created as part of the given test.

eg.

```
public class ServiceTest extends TransactionalTest {
    @InjectMocks
    HistoryService orderHistoryService;

    @Mock
    WebsiteService websiteService;

    ...

}
```

That `websiteService` in the `HistoryService` is not `null` is worrying. It seems like some other injection is happening somewhere and you have ended up with two separate mocked website services. One in your test class and the other in `HistoryService`. You seem to have left out a fair bit of the test classes so it's hard to be sure what is actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Answer : [Try to write unit test case in one class]

Make Sure `websiteService` is `@Mock` in the Service Class.